# Passing ID in URL from One VF Page to Lookup Field

Tags: visualforce, controller

I am passing the Id of record from one VF page to another in a URL parameter.  In the second VF page (AddFile), I need take this Id and set it as a lookup field.  I'm having troubles getting this done.  Anyone know what I am missing?

URL coming from page one (working as expected):

```
/apex/AddFile?account=b04L3211232wEj4IAE
```

AddFile Controller:

```
public virtual without sharing class AddFileController {

@TestVisible private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

public File__c newFile {get;set;}
public String account {get; set;}

public AddRecordController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.stdController = stdController;
}

public virtual PageReference init() {
    if (this.stdController.getId() == null) {
        newFile = new File__c();
        account = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('account'); 
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

AddFile VF Page

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" standardController="File__c" extensions="AddFileController">
<apex:form>
    <div >
        <label>Subject</label>
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!newFile.Subject__c}"/>
    </div>
    <!-- lookup field that needs to be populated -->
    <div >
        <label>Account</label>
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!account}"/>
    </div>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: You say lookup field but you VF tag is an inputtextarea so a bit confused as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to set a lookup field, what VF tag should I be using?

Comment: Well, part of my problem was I was not calling the 'init' action in my VF page. I've got that set now and the Id from the URL is coming into my field. But as @Eric has pointed it, it doesn't look like inputtextarea is the right VF tag to use for setting a lookup field. What would that be?

Comment: @John_Henry If the below answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 1):

So to get a lookup field onto the page it is easier to use a proxy object.

Since the Opportunity as a lookup to the account we will use that as a proxy:

**CLASS**

```
public virtual without sharing class AddFileController {

@TestVisible private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

public File__c newFile {get;set;}
public Opportunity accountLookupProxy {get; set;}

public AddRecordController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.stdController = stdController;
}

public virtual PageReference init() {
    if (this.stdController.getId() == null) {
        newFile = new File__c();
        accountLookupProxy = New Opportunity(); 
        accountLookUpProxy.AccountID = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('account'); 
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" standardController="File__c" extensions="AddFileController">
<apex:form>
    <div >
        <label>Subject</label>
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!newFile.Subject__c}"/>
    </div>
    <!-- lookup field that needs to be populated -->
    <div >
        <label>Account</label>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!accountLookupProxy.AccountID}"/>
    </div>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Now, depending on exactly what you are trying to do this could be done completely differently. If you are trying to use another custom object then there would be no need to use a proxy like this.

**If File__C has a lookup to account then**

**CLASS**

```
public virtual without sharing class AddFileController {

@TestVisible private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

public File__c newFile {get;set;}
public Opportunity accountLookupProxy {get; set;}

public AddRecordController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.stdController = stdController;
}

public virtual PageReference init() {
    if (this.stdController.getId() == null) {
        newFile = new File__c();
        NewFile.Account__c = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('account'); 
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" standardController="File__c" extensions="AddFileController">
<apex:form>
    <div >
        <label>Subject</label>
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!newFile.Subject__c}"/>
    </div>
    <!-- lookup field that needs to be populated -->
    <div >
        <label>Account</label>
        <apex:inputField value="{!newFile.Account__c}"/>
    </div>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

It all depends on what you are trying to do......

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve this by setting the field to the URL parameter in the controller directly.

Comment: Please mark as accepted answer then so the question does not keep getting surfaced as unanswered.